# Google Cloud Healthcare APIs FHIR Search Include Patient but not all resources with Appointment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hl7-fhir, google-cloud-healthcare

I'm trying to run a search for Appointment and include some resources but not others. Specifically trying to avoid including some Binary resources linked as "supportingInfo" which are quite large.

But I'd still like to include Patient, Location, etc.

Using `*` works and includes all related resources: Patient, Location, Practitioner, and unfortunately Binary:

`GET /Appointment?_include=*`

But, none of these include anything other than the Appointments:

`GET /Appointment?_include=Patient:patient`

`GET /Appointment?_include=Location:location`

`GET /Appointment?_include=Patient:actor`

`GET /Appointment?_include=Practitioner:practitioner`

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just a limitation of Google's FHIR API implementation? I've successfully used other, seemingly more advanced search features like `_revinclude` and `_include:iterate` but maybe it's all or nothing? I'm not sure how to go about confirming this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_include needs to specify the Resource and search parameter you're wanting to include.  So for Appointment, it would be:

`GET [base]/Appointment?_include=Appointment:patient,Appointment:location,Appointment:practitioner`

If you wanted to also include some of the resources that an included  resource pointed to, you'd need to do this:
`_include:iterate=Location:organization` would return the organizations pointed to by Locations that were included by your priro include

Comment: You saved me again, Lloyd! Thank you!